# obtener URL y si el campo existe en la misma

Tags: javascript, nodejs

tengo un servidor con ECS5 (no trabaja con async/await) y quiero saber si hay una forma de obtener la url desde donde se llame la función y comprobar si tiene un campo o no, es decir:

puede que se llame desde esta URL:

http://127.0.0.1/home o [http://127.0.0.1/home?type='positivo'](http://127.0.0.1/home?type=%27positivo%27)

poder tomar la url y saber cuando traiga el type...gracias y disculpen pero estoy comenzando...
gracias..

Comment: Digamos que tu servidor puede manejar esas rutas por ejemplo __/home__ y recibir un parámetro por ejemplo ```type``` con su respectivo valor pero creo que no es lo que quieres. Lo que quieres es saber cual es la URL final que mostrará tu servidor no es así?

Comment: no, lo que quiero es saber la url desde donde se llama la funcion y saber si dentro de esa url esta un campo

Comment: Que función? Por favor añade el código y cómo extra puedes poner un ejemplo más realista de lo que quieres, edita tu pregunta por favor